# How to get element in vector without repetition (duplication)?

Tags: matlab

My question is: if I get a vector of element for example `v = [2,3,5,3,5,4,8,9,8]` I want only to get the element (items) without repetition (duplication) for the last example: `result=[2,3,5,4,8,9]`

Answer (score 3):

You should use [unique](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html?refresh=true)

```
v = [2,3,5,3,5,4,8,9,8]
unique(v)

ans =

     2     3     4     5     8     9
```

If you want to keep the same order, use the option 'stable'

```
unique(v,'stable')

ans =

     2     3     5     4     8     9
```